# How to use input mask plugin with alias

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm using the plugin RobinHerbots/Inputmask and I've followed the following guidance https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/wiki/Howto:-Effectively-using-the-data-inputmask-attribute

So my javascript code looks like

```
$('[data-inputmask]').inputmask();

Inputmask.extendAliases({
 'euro': {
   mask: "999-999-999"
 }
});
```

and this is my html

```
<input type="text" data-inputmask="'alias': 'euro'" />
```

The problem is when I move over the input field i get the word euro instead of the input mask, do you know why?

Comment: Have you tried adding `placeholder` attribute to the input with your own string?

Comment: Hi no I haven’t how do I do it?

Comment: `<input placeholder="Format: 999-999-999" type="text" data-inputmask="'alias': 'euro'" />`

Comment: I’ll try it later and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it the easy way and class mask as a parameter.

```
$('.inputmask').inputmask({"mask": "999-999-999"});

<input type="text" class="inputmask" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t because I then need to clone the field so I would like to implement the solution described here https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/221 by the author

Comment: Technically you still can after the clone just call `$new_obj.inputmask({"mask": "999-999-999"});`. and it will fix the mask on the input

Comment: The new object has a different I’d though, generated dynamically when the input is cloned

Comment: @pippo that doesn't actually matter because you just refer to the new object's variable before the inputmask like you would for modifying that new object. I have actually had to do that for many plugins, so its not unique to inputmask. And its a common problem on SO.